# Posix Threads Priorities in C

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, thread-priority

`A thread which is joined to another can't continue its execution untill the thread to which it is joined has been completely executed or terminated.`

Following the above mentioned thread characteristics, the last thread I create in the following code must also print its statements inside the procedure `Func()` but it is not. Why is that?

Second, I am unable to set `priority` for any thread I create in this program. Am I missing something?

Here is the code:

```
void *Func(void *arg);
int main()
{
    pthread_t tid[5];

    pthread_attr_t *tattr;
    struct sched_param param;
    int pr,error,i;

    do
    {
        if( (tattr=(pthread_attr_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_attr_t)) )==NULL)
        {
            printf("Couldn't allocate memory for attribute object\n");
        }
    } while(tattr==NULL);

    if(error=pthread_attr_init(tattr))
    {
        printf(stderr,"Attribute initialization failed with error %s\n",strerror(error));
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&pr);

        param.sched_priority=pr;
        error=pthread_attr_setschedparam(tattr,&param);

        if(error!=0)
        {
            printf("failed to set priority\n");
        }

        if(i%2==0)
        {
            if(error=pthread_attr_setdetachstate(tattr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED))
            {
                fprintf(stderr,"Failed to set thread attributes with error %s\n",strerror(error));
            }
        }
        else if(error=pthread_attr_setdetachstate(tattr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE))
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Failed to set thread attributes with error %s\n",strerror(error));
        }

        pthread_create(&tid[i],tattr,Func,tattr);

        pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
        printf("waiting for thread %d\n",i);
    }

    free(tattr);

    printf("All threads terminated\n");
    return 0;
}

void *Func(void *arg)
{
    pthread_attr_t *tattr=(pthread_attr_t *)arg;
    int state,error;

    struct sched_param param;

    error=pthread_attr_getdetachstate(tattr,&state);

    if(error==0 && state==PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED)
    {
        printf(" My state is DETACHED\n");
    }
    else if(error==0 && state==PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE)
    {
        printf(" My state is JOINABLE\n");
    }

    error=pthread_attr_getschedpolicy(tattr,&param);

    if(error==0)
    {
        printf(" My Priority is %d\n",param.sched_priority);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Check the return value for pthread_join, I bet it returns an error due to the thread being detached.

Comment: Ok. So when I set thread attribute to `detach`, how can I make main thread or any other thread to wait for a thread with detach attribute?
And why can't I set the priority for the thread

Comment: Why would you make it detached if you want to wait for it? Main reason `detach` exists is to avoid having to call `pthread_join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your operating system?

The meaning of the members of `struct sched_param` is implementation defined for scheduling policy `SCHED_OTHER`.

For example, on GNU/Linux, unless the scheduling policy is `SCHED_RR` or `SCHED_FIFO`, the `sched_priority` member is not used and must be set to 0.

Other than that, the fifth thread (the last) also prints its state and priority.

Comment: @Alfred, Ubuntu is GNU/Linux. Check `sched_setscheduler(2)` manpage, for a somewhat detailed description all the available scheduling policies. Note that static priority is applicable only to `SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR`, for which the process has to have appropriate privileges.